# Requesting subset of json key-value pairs in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a json url (http://something.json) which I need to access through PHP. However the json file is huge and I only need one key-value pair from it. Is it possible to request a subset of key-value pairs given a url, to minimize network traffic?

Comment: It might be possible if it's being served by an API that supports such operations, but it depends on the site.

Comment: I don't think so, since the file is parsed by your PHP script. So it needs to be loaded first.

Comment: There is no thing like "json url" or "json key-value pair". [`JSON`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a text representation of a data structure. A data structure that, indeed, usually consists of key-value pairs but this is not a requirement, PHP happily encodes as JSON and decodes back simple type values like integers or strings. Being a data structure you have to re-create it in memory from the text representation ("decode" the JSON) in order to work with it. The short answer is: no, it's not possible to request only a subset of the data, except if the server provides such an option.

Answer (score 1):

If the JSON file is output by some API that you can ask to only give you some of it, otherwise no.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough knowledge about your architecture but first thing comes to mind is pre-fetching or caching the json file to a local storage and reading from that location when needed and process the file as you like.

The other option might be running separate virtual server/aws ec2 instance in free tier etc. and periodically fetch and process the json file, save the needed key-value pair and serve the key-value pair from that service from a different url/ip address on your choice.
This one is for sure needs more effort, you can determine if it's worth it or not.